# zero as a fraction

Tags: number-theory

So I know that 0/x with limits is always infinity. Now I would like to ask, what if we viewed zero as a number with no quantity but with value? Could we then split zero up into fractions to denotate the level of emptiness? Could we rethink the way we see zero? Should zero include a positive and negative value? I know this is against everything I've been told, but I can't help but stretch the parameters to see if there is something that we are missing. Zero essentially makes the amount of numbers to exist an odd number, since everything is mirrored; so would zero's value change whether or not it is being divided by an even or odd number. Would the odd number keep it at zero while the even gave two values?

Comment: These are interesting thoughts but all lead to different parts of regular arithmetic breaking down and not working consistently. As such to make such ideas works you often need to redefine aspects of arithmetic. This is possible but you end up with something which is different/very different to what is the regular/common version of arithmetic. $$$$ Some examples of similar ideas is infinitesimals in non-standard analysis.

Comment: Well we already use it differently depending on the type of formula being used, like the limits that were mentioned. So didn't we already sort of "bend" our arithmetic? I've have read up on this, but I'm not satisfied with the answers. On a graph, the space of zero (and every number quantity on the graph) holds the same space as 1, so couldn't we get 0/1=1 since there is that same value of space; and there is only 1 instance of any number existing as a whole number. And zero only exists once. Maybe zero needs to be treated differently in mathematical situations, and that's what we are missing.

Comment: I can sort of understand what you are asking. As others have suggested please collect your thoughts and present them in a more organized way. As others have said we are very happy to answer your question(s) but as they stand its unclear what you mean. A clear question will be taken off hold then we can answer it.

Answer (score 3):

You may be surprised at the amount of downvotes your question racked up, so let me explain. Basically, your question is not a mathematical question. A mathematical questions takes some well defined things and asks a well defined question about them.

For example, "even number" is a well defined thing, and "greater than" is a well defined thing, so we may ask the question

> Does there exist an even number, greater than $13$

And we may answer this question "yes", and prove it by saying "an example of such a number is $14$.

---

Your question, on the other hand, uses language that is not mathematical. For example, you first say:

> 0/x with limits is always infinity

Which actually makes no sense. Even I don't know what you wanted to say. You *can* say:

> For every non-zero real number $x$, the value of $\frac0x$ is $0$.

which is a true mathematical statement, or you can say

> The limit of $\frac0x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is $0$.

But not what you said.

Then, you ask:

> what if we viewed zero as a number with no quantity but with value

Which, again, is **not** a mathematical question. First of all, what does "viewing" of a number mean? Second of all, what is "quantity" and what is "value"? These are all vaguely defined terms, and without cementing what you mean by them the question **cannot** be answered.

---

You continue by saying:

> Should zero include a positive and negative value?

Which again, makes no sense. What do you mean by "include"? In what sense does a number (zero) **include** any value at all?

Your next claim is

> Zero essentially makes the amount of numbers to exist an odd number, since everything is mirrored

Which I do not understand. The "amount of numbers to exist" sounds like "the size of the set of numbers", but since that set is **infinite**, it's size is infinity, so most certainly not an odd number (because **it isn't even a number**!)

---

**EDIT**:

You now claim:

> as x approaches zero, the limit of n/x approaches infinity.

which is sort of true, i.e. it's true if $n>0$.

OK, so now your original statement is true. You still haven't addressed the other points in my answer, so your questio is still very unclear (and not really mathematical).

Comment: Sorry, I see where I made a huge mistake, let me correct my incorrect logic.

Comment: I do appreciate your interest, I understand I do not have the best math vocabulary (still a student), but we all have to start somewhere. And in all honesty, I couldn't think of a better location. And I'm trying to get a better understanding. Sorry if my thoughts may seem jumbled. This is what I meant in respect to limits: As x approaches (insert any real number or infinity), the limit of x/0 approaches (positive or negative depending on the direction towards the value of x) infinity.

Comment: Assuming zero is always non-negative then it has no mirror value, but every other value can have a positive and negative value, even infinity can be assigned a negative value.

Comment: @Bealle I understand you are a beginner. Nothing wrong with that. Please don't take my comments as an attack on you, personally. I am simply pointing out your mistakes so you can correct them. And again, your sentence is incorrect. The limit of $x/0$ does not exist, because $x/0$ is **not defined**.

Comment: @Bealle Sure, all numbers except zero have a mirror value. That **does not mean** that the "amount of numbers is odd".

Comment: Limits at infinity create asymptotes on the graph, which yes does make it undefined. The fact we say it is not defined just makes me more interested in why.

Comment: @Bealle You're missing my point. Entirely. You are asking 10 different questions and jumping from one question to another all the time. That's not how we do thigns in math. Ask *one* well defined question and you will get an answer.

Comment: Another correction on the limit, I meant to say: as x approaches zero, the limit of n/x approaches infinity. And with as many negative feelings people harbor towards each other, I don't care about anyone's opinion that disrespects the effort to learn or questions that have passionate curiosity.

Comment: @Bealle Again, I am not attacking you in person. I appreciate the fact that you are trying to learn. However, I **am** telling you what you are doing wrong, because that's how people learn. It's nothing personal, and I was not disrespectful. Your questions were erratic, that was a fact. And that's not how we do things in math. I can't help you if you feel offended by me telling you that. Also, see the edit to my answer.

Comment: I am jumping, but that is to see if there are connections. You have answered to the best of your ability, which is greatly appreciated. I was also curious to see if anyone would mention any theories that I could even research, since all that I can find is the "undefined" answer.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't offended by you, just stating I don't care about the down votes, and those people who just want to be negative online.

Comment: @Bealle Actually, the downvotes are not a message saying "you suck and you should feel bad". Downvoting a question can either happen because no effort was shown (clearly *not* the case here) or for other reasons. For example, the question currently is *vague* and *needs clarification*. As I explained, you need to ask the question using mathematical language in order for the question to be appropriate here. There may be nothing wrong with the question (for example, maybe it's perfectly fine for philosophers), bit on this site, it doesn't fit.

Comment: @Bealle It's impossible for you to check the motivation of the downvoters. So any interpretation of it is misplaced. Secondly: cherish this nice answer to your question.

Comment: @drhab Basically, you said in 20 words what I said in 200. Well done :D